# Rustrover reports "unresolved references” while using proto files

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, rustrover

Just the red report messages and everything funcions well.I guess it's probably caused by rustrover its self but dont know where to fix it.The red error looks really annoying.

The most wired thing is that in client.rs everything goes well but in server.rs it just reports the error.

[the reports in server.rs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYx5F.png)

[there's no problem in client.rs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fn2x.png)

And here is the build.rs,it funcs well and generates helloworld.rs in /target/debug/build successfully

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  tonic_build::configure().compile(&["proto/helloworld.proto"], &["proto"])?;
  Ok(())
}
```

All at the beginning it was client.rs who reports the error and after I updated rustrover to 2023.3,it moved to server.rs.

And Cargo.toml here:

```
[package]
name = "helloworld_tonic"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
[[bin]] 
name = "helloworld-server"
path = "src/server.rs"
[[bin]] 
name = "helloworld-client"
path = "src/client.rs"
[dependencies]
tonic = "0.10.2"
prost = "0.12.1"
tokio = { version = "1.23.0", features = ["full"] }
[build-dependencies]
tonic-build = "0.10.2"
```

Comment: How have you set up `Cargo.toml`? Usually you'd need either `lib.rs` or `main.rs` as the root of the crate.

Comment: I add Cargo.toml above.But I think my project is going well in fact,it's just Rustrover failed to recogonize it.......@Holloway

Comment: You should probably adhere to the standard project layout, move `src/client.rs` to `src/bin/helloworld-client.rs` and remove the `[[bin]]` section from `Cargo.toml` and similar for the `server`. It would also be preferable to put the types in `src/lib.rs` and include them from both server and client instead of compiling them twice.

Comment: Please [don't upload images of texts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) (which the error messages are) just add the output of `cargo check` as formatted text blocks in the question. And please provide a [mre] that would include your `proto/helloworld.proto` for this problem.

Comment: If it's a pure RustRover problem and not actually a problem seen with the Rust compiler then you should probably file a bug for it instead of asking a question here.

Comment: Thank u for ur adivce，I'm new here so I may make a lot mistakes asking questions.I check out th bug track log of RR just now and I've found similar issues.After switching to VScode everything goes fine.And it's pretty sure that it's RR's fault.So should I leave the question here or just delete it?as u said it's not a "question".@cafce25